# regex to remove paths from file names but only when path begins with a given pattern

Tags: regex, perl

I have a file containing file names (amongst other things). Only some of the file names are at the start of a line in the file:

```
~/remove/me/myexec.pl /some/other/path/exec.pl
/yet/another/path/pipeit.pl | ~/remove/me/subdir/tome.pl
~/remove/me/deeply/nested/exec.pl
```

I want to remove the file path of any file that starts with `~/remove/me`. I also want any sub-directories of `~/remove/me` to be removed.

**Here is my desired output from the above:**

```
myexec.pl /some/other/path/exec.pl
/yet/another/path/pipeit.pl | tome.pl
exec.pl
```

The paths of files not beginning with `~/remove/me` must be left alone.

The nearest I can get is using a regex like this:

```
s{~/remove/me/[^/]*?}{}gxms
```

But this does not deal with subdirectories properly, giving me the following output:

```
myexec.pl /some/other/path/exec.pl
/yet/another/path/pipeit.pl | subdir/tome.pl
deeply/nested/exec.pl
```

**Can anyone come up with a regex to solve this?**

Comment: Are filenames separated by whitespace or can they be separated by other tokens like pipe symbol? For example, no space on either side of pipe: `/yet/another/path/pipeit.pl|tome.pl`

Comment: @HåkonHægland the filenames will always be separated by whitespace

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Another way - `s{~/remove/me/(?:[^/\s]*?/)*}{}g`

```
 ~/remove/me/
 (?:                           # Optional - Many non-spaced subdir's
      [^/\s]*? 
      /
 )*
```

Comment: why use a nongreedy quantifier after a negated character class? Wouldn't a negated character class like `[^\s]*` always be nongreedy?

Comment: Its just a habit I have. Anything with `*,+` will always be greedy. However, you can include other characters in the class, that might be downstream, that act as limiters. This allows you to make a more robust expression that is minimul (not in this case though). Example: `(?:".*?"|'.*?'|[^>]*?)+`

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
~\/remove\/me[^\s]*\/(?=[^\s]+)
```

---

[Regex live here.](https://regex101.com/r/oC1yM8/3)

Explaining:

```
 ~\/remove\/me            # starts with "~/remove/me"
 [^\s]*\/                 # match any non-space till last slash "/"
 (?=[^\s]+)               # match without taking the name and extension
```

Hope it helps.

---

Answer (score 1):

a quick one, not perfect but I think it's doing what's required - of course it could be optimised.

```
my $text = "~/remove/me/myexec.pl /some/other/path/exec.pl\n/yet/another/path/pipeit.pl | ~/remove/me/subdir/tome.pl\n~/remove/me/deeply/nested/exec.pl";

$text =~ s/~\/remove\/me[a-zA-Z0-9\/]*\/([a-zA-Z0-9.]+)/$1/g;
print $text;
```

results the following:

```
myexec.pl /some/other/path/exec.pl
/yet/another/path/pipeit.pl | tome.pl
exec.pl
```